# Splice not removing item from Array

Tags: xpages-ssjs

This looks like it should work but for some reason the indexed value is not being removed. I think it must be something really simple but???
Here is the code:

```
var debug:Boolean = true;
    var rtn:Array = database.getView("vwWFSApplicationsEnabled").getColumnValues(0);
    var i:Integer = rtn.indexOf("Admin");
    if (debug) print ("Position of Admin = " + i + " rtn = " + rtn.toString() )
        
    if (i >= 0){
        if (debug) print("In splice  " )
        rtn.splice(i , 1);
        if (debug) print("after Splice  " + rtn.toString() )
    }       
    return rtn.unshift("--- Select Application ---");
```

When it runs I get this in the log:

> HTTP JVM: Position of Admin = 1 rtn = [Absence Requests, Admin, Demo]
>
> HTTP JVM: In splice
>
> HTTP JVM: after Splice  [Absence Requests, Admin, Demo]

i is being set in the indexOf to 1 which is correct so the splice(i, 1) should remove the value Admin from the array but after the splice the value Admin is still in the list.
I've used the split in other situations and it works there but I can't see any difference in this code.

Comment: That looks basically correct. Is your getView() returning a real plain Javascript array? Or probably something different which does not implement splice correctly?

Comment: This looks like TypeScript to me.

Comment: @TomMettam TypeScript has no (built-in) `Integer` type -- the `number` primitive is used instead to declare a numeric variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the example you have your own custom `Array` type. I say this because:

- `Array#toString` doesn't produce output like that (it doesn't put `[]` around its outputs, and it would put quotes around string values)
- `Array` is not a legal declaration in TypeScript
- Your code doesn't work

Whatever custom `Array` type you are using simply doesn't implement `splice` correctly and we can't diagnose that problem without the relevant code.

Comment: my tags got messed up this is in ssjs in XPages.

Comment: Literally all you have to do to answer this question is Google "ssjs splice" and you'll land on a blog post explaining that splice doesn't work in ssjs.

Answer (score 0):

`NotesView.getColumnValues(n)` returns a Vector ([java.util.Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)) and not a SSJS Array (com.ibm.jscript.std.ArrayObject). Hence you have to use `Vector.remove(i)` to get rid of the given element. Also, Vector does not support unshift - you would have to replace it with `Vector.add(0,x)`.

In case you decide to go with a different approach, namely to convert the Vector to a SSJS Array and keep the rest of your code untouched I want to state the following: `Array.splice()` definitely works in SSJS (at least since Domino 8.5.3). If older versions do not support it you can easily write a prototype for Array.splice. Additionally, keep in mind that in the current SSJS implementation, Array.splice works slightly different than in client-side JavaScript (CSJS): In CSJS it returns the removed elements, while in SSJS it returns the newly created array.